# Quickblox - How to show the data using custom object with parameters IOS

Tags: ios, quickblox, custom-object

I am working on an app and I am working on a contact list that I want to get filtered. Therefore I am using custom objects of quickblox, here is my code:

```
- (NSArray *)idsFromContactListItems { 
   NSMustableArray *idsToFetch = [NSMustableArray new];
   NSArray *contactListItems = self.contactList; 
   for (QBContactListItem *item in contactListItems) { 
       NSMutableDictionary *getRequest = [NSMutableDictionary new];
       [getRequest setObject:@"personal" forKey:@"identifier"];
       if ([QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName=@"cards" extendedRequest:getRequest delegate:self]){
           idsToFetch addObject:@(item.userID)];}
           else {}; 
   } 
   return idsToFetch;
  };
```

My array idsToFetch returns all the values but there is only 1 in my custom object class that has personal in identifier.

Answer (score 1):

`[QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName=@"cards" extendedRequest:getRequest delegate:self]` will call `completedWithResult:` method on self(please note that this is deprecated api and it was removed in the latest 2.3.0.4, but still available in the latest 2.2.5 SDK with old API 1.x support)

```
[QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName=@"cards" extendedRequest:getRequest delegate:self]
```

will call

```
- (void)completedWithResult:(QBResult *)result {
// in result you will have QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult
QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult *res = (QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult *)result;
// to get your items in array with identifier == presonal you can use
NSArray *customObjects = res.objects;

}
```